# Model alias in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, model

I have definition of my model. Here is:

```
Ext.define('KP.model.account.AccountList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    alias: 'model.d_AccountList',

    fields: ['key', 'number', 'personal_account', 'full_name', 'adress', 'pu']
});
```

So, I want to create this model **by alias**. 
Or define store, what use this model like this:

```
model: 'd_AccountList'
```

How can I do that?
Thanks!

P.S.:Maybe my alias is wrong...

Comment: `model: 'KP.model.account.AccountList'` is the only way I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware of there is none.

Comment: For store alias exist, for view exist, why there are no alias for model? Is there any way to create models by short names, independently physical path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't create an alias for model, there is not alias property on Ext.data.Model.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model

```
Ext.define('model.d_AccountList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',    
    fields: ['key', 'number', 'personal_account', 'full_name', 'adress', 'pu']
});

var accountList = Ext.Create('model.d_AccountList', {
    key: 11,
    number: 33,
    personal_account: 4553463
})
```

Comment: There are no information such as: "You can't create model by alias"

Comment: Define like : 'model.d_AccountList' and create like : 'model.d_AccountList' - it is not work...

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

The 'alias' member is existent to all ExtJS classes that inherit from Ext.Class. That includes models. You can use whatever alias you want as long as it does not collide with other ones. It's best if you divide them by domain. There are already some domains out there like 'widget','store,'proxy'. Whether you need to specify the domain or the full alias depends on instantiating class when using the alias config. For instance, if you refer to a proxy with alias of 'proxy.myProxyAlias', in a store you should use:
    proxy:'myProxyAlias'
Reason being is that the the Ext.data.Store class will automatically pre-pend 'proxy.'. There are few others that are doing the same trick:

- defining 'reader' from association
- defining 'writer'/'reader' from a proxy
- defining 'reader' from a form
- defining 'axis'/'series' from a chart
- defining 'proxy'/another 'store' from a store
- defining a 'widget'

In your case that you use really gives you that trick for model classes, so if you define a model with alias:
    alias: 'model.myModel'
on the store you'll have to use either the full model class name or:
    xtype: 'model.myModel'

Hope it helps.