# How can I reference a Model from a Store in ExtJS using alias?

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewmodel, alias, store

I have a model:

```js
Ext.define('MyAPP.model.myMod', {
   extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
   alias   : 'model.myMod',
});
```

And a store:

```js
   Ext.define('MyAPP.store.MyStore', {
      extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
      model  : 'MyAPP.model.myMod',
});
```

How can I reference the model on the store using the alias?
I'm looking to be able to reference using only `model: 'model.myMod',` or `model: 'myMod'`.

I can't get this to work, I have always to reference it using full path: `MyAPP.model.myMod`.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745935/model-alias-in-extjs) answer your question? It is an old post but as far as I know the situation is the same today.

Comment: @PeterKoltai last post says I could use `xtype: 'model.myModel'` but this doesn't work. So maybe the only way is to have the full name.

Comment: I think it is the only way. `xtype` only works with `Ext.create`, and you can also use `Ext.createByAlias` to create using alias, but for this store definition, `model` property is the full name, at least that's how I've seen using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference a Model from a Store by using `alias`. BUT, you can use the property `alternateClassName` for your Model, like this:

```js
Ext.define('MyAPP.model.myMod', {
   extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
   alternateClassName : 'myMod',
});
```

```js
Ext.define('MyAPP.store.MyStore', {
      extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
      model  : 'myMod',
});
```

Now, you're able to reference using only `model: 'myMod'` from your Store.
No need to reference it using full path: `MyAPP.model.myMod`.

Answer (score 0):

I can not help to define and use alias property on the model.

This does not work out of the box (without overwrites) because models are extending Ext.Base.

The alias property is getting defined in classes extending Ext.Class.

And the model property on the store expects a className or entityName, if you do not set a custom entityName, className is the default.

One way to achieve this, using a shorthand name could be something like this:

```
Ext.define('foo.bar.test', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    schema: {
         namespace: 'foo.bar'
     },
   fields:[ 'name', 'email', 'phone']
})

Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    model: 'test',
    data: [
        { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

---

Mentioned options using xtype might work, i would not rely on it, because xtypes are designed for components.

- https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-xtype

Some more resources to this topic:

- https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#property-entityName
- https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.data.schema.Schema.html
- https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.data.schema.Namer.html